# pandas dataframe restructuring

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so:

### Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(3), 'b': np.arange(3)-1})
```

### Desired output:

```
df_rearranged = pd.DataFrame({'data': [0,1,2,-1,0,1], 'origin': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']})
```

I have found a (hacky) way of doing this:

### Attempt:

```
subset_1 = df[['a']]
subset_1['origin'] = 'a'
subset_1.rename(columns={'a':'data'}, inplace=True)

subset_2 = df[['b']]
subset_2['origin'] = 'b'
subset_2.rename(columns={'b':'data'}, inplace=True)

df_rearranged = subset_1.append(subset_2)
```

This works, but it quickly becomes impractical when I want to pool larger numbers of columns. Also, I feel that there should be a function in pandas that does this by default, but I am lacking the keywords to find it. Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You want melt, `df.melt()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with change order columns by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df1 = df.melt(var_name='origin', value_name='data').reindex(['data','origin'], axis=1)
print (df1)
   data origin
0     0      a
1     1      a
2     2      a
3    -1      b
4     0      b
5     1      b
```

Or DataFrame constructor with [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) and [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), obviously working with better performance:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'data':df.values.ravel(), 'origin':np.repeat(df.columns, len(df))})
print (df1)
   data origin
0     0      a
1    -1      a
2     1      a
3     0      b
4     2      b
5     1      b
```